# How do i generate multiple file outputs with T4 templates in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

This does not seem possible using an asp.net 5 project or a class library package project using VS 2015 without VS Hanging.

I have tried various examples using the TemplateFileManager, files get generated, however VS just hangs indicating it's busy and does not recover.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a  fix?

**UPDATE:**

There seems to be an issue with generating files into a class library (package) project type. Even if I move the T4 template out into an standard class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another got at this following the release of .Net Core 1.0 and now have it working.

When using

```
fileManager.StartNewFile(dataAccessFileName, generatedFilesTargetProject, generatedFilesTargetFolder, fileProperties);
```

It only worked when specifying all 4 parameters, making sure the target folder is correct.